# How can I use "is" to check or an exact class (not a descendant)?

Tags: delphi

```
TBase = class(TObject)
...

TDerived = class(Tbase)
...

if myObject is TBase then ...
```

can I code this somehow and have it return false if myObject is of class TDerived?

Comment: The answer 'how' is below, but why do you want to do this?  It sounds a symptom of a bad design to me.  If you add more info then people answering might be able to give a fuller answer, including other approaches to your full problem.

Comment: There are cases when it's necessary to check for the exact class type.
We use this in our ORM framework.
Please not also that "is" can be replaced by "InheritsFrom" method, and actually "is" is just a call to this method. I never use "is", but always "InheritsFrom".

Comment: @David M  +1 for "bad design" ... while my inital thought when posting this was that it was obviouly necessary, you comment makes me think that it has a code smell

Comment: @A.Bouchez (+1) but, how would you code it then for "if object is exactly of this class and not descended from it" ?

Comment: My use case was that I wanted an abstract/base class in Delphi 6 that I didn't want instantiated by mistake; Delphi 6 doesn't have abstract classes. I previously got away with having a constructor in the 'abstract' class that raised an exception, but now the abstract class has something to do in the constructor (and descendants now call 'inherited' to make sure the consturctor is called; before they didn't on purpose). Maybe a code smell still, but I appreciate the Q&A nonetheless; improves my previous solution. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you need exact class type check use ClassType method:

```
type

TBase = class(TObject)
end;

TDerived = class(Tbase)
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 A: TBase;

begin
  A:= TBase.Create;
  if A.ClassType = TBase then ShowMessage('TBase');  // shown
  A.Free;
  A:= TDerived.Create;
  if A.ClassType = TBase then ShowMessage('TBase again'); // not shown
  A.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ClassType method, or just check PPointer(aObject)^=aClassType.

```
begin
  A:= TBase.Create;
  if A.ClassType = TBase then ShowMessage('TBase');  // shown
  if PPointer(A)^ = TBase then ShowMessage('TBase');  // shown
  A.Free;
  A:= TDerived.Create;
  if PPointer(A)^ = TBase then ShowMessage('TBase again'); // not shown
  if A.ClassType = TBase then ShowMessage('TBase again');  // not shown
  A.Free;
end;
```

If your code is inside a class method, you can use self to get the class value:

```
class function TBase.IsDerivedClass: boolean;
begin
  result := self=TDerivedClass;
end;
```

Comment: Poking in VMT internals, specially without using proper constants is FPC incompatible. Better use classtype

Comment: FPC uses the same definition: ClassType is just a class function which  returns TClass(Pointer(Self)). So using PPointer(AAobject)^ should be FPC compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Better way;

```
type

TBase = class(TObject)
end;

TDerived = class(Tbase)
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 A, B: TObject;

begin
  A:= TBase.Create;
  if A.ClassType = TBase then ShowMessage('A is Exacly TBase');  // shown
  if A is TBase then ShowMessage('A is TBase or SubClass of TBase');  // shown
  if A is TDerived then ShowMessage('A is TDerived or SubClass of TDerived ');  // NOT shown!! 
  A.Free;

  B:= TDerived.Create;
  if B.ClassType = TBase then ShowMessage('TBase again'); // not shown
  if B is TBase then ShowMessage('B is TBase or SubClass of TBase');  // shown
  if B is TDerived then ShowMessage('B is TDerived or SubClass of TDerived ');  // shown!! 
  B.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering this ancient question. This is the only answer which uses "is", as requested.